# Perfectly capturing a perfect forwarder (universal reference) in a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, perfect-forwarding

So I have a perfect forwarder, and I want to appropriately capture it in a lambda, such that R-values are copied in, and L-values are captured by reference.  However simply using std::forward doesn't do the job, as evidenced by this code:

```
#include<iostream>

class testClass
{
public:
   testClass() = default;
   testClass( const testClass & other ) { std::cout << "COPY C" << std::endl; }
   testClass & operator=(const testClass & other ) { std::cout << "COPY A" << std::endl; }
};

template< class T>
void testFunc(T && t)
   { [test = std::forward<T>(t)](){}(); }

int main()
{
   testClass x;
   std::cout << "PLEASE NO COPY" << std::endl;
   testFunc(x);
   std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;

   std::cout << "COPY HERE" << std::endl;
   testFunc(testClass());
   std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this with

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

Produces the output

```
PLEASE NO COPY
COPY C
DONE
COPY HERE
COPY C
DONE
```

In a perfect world, I would like to only have the "COPY C" appear in the rvalue case, not the lvalue case.

My work around would be to use a helper function overloaded for L- and R- values, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move capture in lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda)

Comment: @NirFriedman That question explains move captures and the whole generalised mechanism, but I don't think it provides any answer for a perfect-forwarding capture. The straightforward way (which the OP tried) apparently doesn't work.

Comment: @Angew good catch, my bad. Apologies to the OP.

Comment: No apologies necessary :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
[test = std::conditional_t<
             std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
             std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<T>>,
             T>{std::forward<T>(t)}]
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/HdSEze)

but providing helper function seems more readable

Comment: Seems as good as anything else.  Good to know I'm not missing anything :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Apparently `[&t]` would suffice provided that you'd forward `t` when used inside the lambda body according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831637/4224575)

Comment: I mean assuming the appropriate behavior would be to move rvalues and reference lvalues (I know see the OP wants to copy rvalues)

Comment: @LorahAttkins: That assumes also that lifetime of lambda is shorter than the captured variable.