# How to pass a c++ functor rvalue reference to a capture of a lambda ?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following function

```
template<class Function>
void f(Function&& g) {
    h(..., [&g](){g();});
}
```

It's a function `f` accepting a function, a lambda or a functor as argument. Inside it calls the function `h` to which I pass a lambda as argument that is calling `g` and receives `g` by capture.

1. Should I pass `g` or `&g` in the capture field of the lambda ?
2. Will the functor be copied with the above code ?

Comment: Normally function-like objects are passed by value. Copying them should be extremely cheap. If your objects are not like this, you are probably doing something not entirely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you capture `g` by reference, that is, with the syntax `&g` shown in your snippet, no copy will be performed. This is the preferred way. You should only copy if the lambda might be called after `f` finishes, which potentially implies a destruction of the object `g` refers to.
In that case, forwarding could be cheaper though:

```
template<class Function>
void f(Function&& g) {
    h(…, [g=std::forward<Function>(g)] {g();});
}
```

Comment: Note that here, you do a copy/move of the original `g`. see [perfectly-capturing-a-perfect-forwarder-universal-reference-in-a-lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410209/perfectly-capturing-a-perfect-forwarder-universal-reference-in-a-lambda/31410880#31410880)

Comment: @Jarod42 That was my intention.

Comment: See @Dieter's answer if one needs an equivalent solution that works with c++11

Answer (score 2):

You might do this:

```
template<class Function>
void f(Function&& g) {
    Function f(std::move(g));
    int additional = 0;
    h(..., [&f, additional](){f(additional);});
}
```

Comment: This answer has the benefit to work with c++11. The answer of @Columbo requires c++14. I picked his answer as valid answer because it's the new standard way to do it. But I'll use your answer until I switch to c++14. Your contribution was helpful.

Comment: AFAICS, This way has no benefit compared to @chmikes original approach whatsoever. First of all, you `move` when you should `forward`. Secondly, `f` is captured by reference, and its lifetime doesn't exceed `g`'s, so actually `f` is superfluous.

Comment: @columbo Apparently my compiler (4.9.2) requires that `f` is passed by reference. This code works. Not sure of the difference it would make to use `forward`.

Comment: @chmike …what about `g` being an lvalue reference to some object that's to be used after `f` is called? Remember, the parameter is a forwarding reference, not an rvalue one. And yeah, of course this code - after fixing the aforementioned bug - works, but introducing `f` serves no purpose at all. One could just capture `g` by reference and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a lambda that accepts no arguments and returns nothing. But you already have such a functor: `g`!. You should just *forward* it:

```
template<class Function>
void f(Function&& g) {
    h(..., std::forward<Function>(g));
}
```

Comment: I suspect that OP just shortened it, and in reality the lambda does more.

Comment: @Ishamael Then OP should put what OP wants to do in the question so that I don't have to guess.

Comment: As @Ishamael said, I stripped the code to it's simplest form. The lambda does much more than call `g()` and `g()` has arguments and return a result. You are right @Barry, I should have made it explicit so that the lambda isn't optimized out in the answers.