# parameter pack expansion not working in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I am learning variadic templates by doing some exercises and I am stuck when it comes to parameter pack expansion in lambda

So, my idea is to write a timer class whose payload will be callable, But I get a compilation error when I try to expand the parameter pack inside a lambda function..

> gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

```
   template<typename F, typename... Args>
   struct timer
   {   
      timer(const std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds, F call, Args&&... args)
      {   
         m_timer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(
               timer_manager::instance().get_io_service(),
               std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + milliseconds
         );  

         //m_timer->async_wait(call, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
         m_timer->async_wait([=](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
             call(std::forward<Args>(args)...); //Error here
         }); 
      }   

      std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::steady_timer> m_timer;
   };


   // Helper to create the timer
   template<typename F, typename... Args>
   timer<F,Args...> create_timer(const std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds,F callable, Args&& ...args)
   {   
      return timer<F,Args...>(milliseconds, std::forward<F>(callable), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
```

Main program to use it:

```
auto timer = timer::create_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000), []()                                                                                                                  
{
   std::cout << "timer fired in main" << std::endl;
   payload::execute(10);           
 });
```

Error:

```
home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp: In lambda function:
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp:36:43: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
                   call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                                           ^
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp:36:43: note:         ‘args’
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct timer::timer<F, Args>::timer(std::chrono::milliseconds, F, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::__lambda1; Args = {}; std::chrono::milliseconds = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >]::__lambda0’:
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp:35:10:   required from ‘timer::timer<F, Args>::timer(std::chrono::milliseconds, F, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::__lambda1; Args = {}; std::chrono::milliseconds = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >]’
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp:50:99:   required from ‘timer::timer<F, Args ...> timer::create_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds, F, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::__lambda1; Args = {}; std::chrono::milliseconds = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >]’
/home/samdaniel/src/main.cpp:21:11:   required from here
/home/samdaniel/timer/src/timer.hpp:36:43: error: using invalid field ‘timer::timer<F, Args>::timer(std::chrono::milliseconds, F, Args&& ...)::__lambda0::__args’
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/coding_with_me.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/coding_with_me.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

New example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

namespace test
{
   template<typename F, typename... Args>
   void callback_dispatcher(F call, Args&& ...args )
   {   
      std::cout << "callback_dispatcher>" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "enter <<< " << std::endl;                                                                                                 
      auto invoke_me = [=](){
         call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      };  
      invoke_me();
   }   
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Main entered..." << std::endl;


   test::callback_dispatcher([](int a)
         {
         std::cout << "void(int) lambda dispatched with a = " << a << std::endl;
         },5);

   std::cout << "Main exited..." << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
src/generic_callback.cc: In lambda function:
src/generic_callback.cc:11:34: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
          call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                                  ^
src/generic_callback.cc:11:34: note:         ‘args’
src/generic_callback.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...) [with F = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (plo_callback_tester::*)()>(std::_Placeholder<1>)>; Args = {plo_callback_tester* const}]::__lambda0’:
src/generic_callback.cc:12:7:   required from ‘void test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...) [with F = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (plo_callback_tester::*)()>(std::_Placeholder<1>)>; Args = {plo_callback_tester* const}]’
src/generic_callback.cc:25:101:   required from here
src/generic_callback.cc:11:34: error: using invalid field ‘test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...)::__lambda0::__args’
src/generic_callback.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::__lambda1; Args = {int}]::__lambda0’:
src/generic_callback.cc:12:7:   required from ‘void test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::__lambda1; Args = {int}]’
src/generic_callback.cc:41:13:   required from here
src/generic_callback.cc:11:34: error: using invalid field ‘test::callback_dispatcher(F, Args&& ...)::__lambda0::__args’
```

Comment: I'm not sure (which is why this is a comment instead of an answer), but I think you want to do `std::forward<Args...>(args...)`; that is, move the `...` inside the parentheses and template parameter list. I think the template parameters are also unnecessary here, but again I’m not sure.

Comment: @DanielH: no, `std::forward<Args>(args)...` would be correct if `Args&&...` was a forwarding reference pack. In the constructor  `std::move(args)...` would suffice.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b291d1dff8829497 -- after eliminating stuff that shouldn't change the error, there is no error in either of these compilers.  Please provide an actual [MCVE] that both reproduces the problem, and eliminates all of those extra unimportant dependencies.  Unless you think `timer_manager` and all the asio stuff actually causes the parameter pack does not expand error, which I don't believe.  Admittedly these are later versions of the compiler, but I will leave it to *you* to generate a [MCVE] in your compiler rather than trying to read your mind.

Comment: @Yakk, add a parameter to the lambda that is being used as a callback and things break - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15c0bf4fc22316e6 , but I'm not sure what happens with the types of the parameter pack during the capture in side the lambda and why it breaks:(

Comment: But yeah, removing the `std::forward` which seems unneeded inside the lambda solves the problems with arguments. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Yakk, I will post a new example

Comment: @rudolf That is a different error, and easy to explain; you cannot forward const copies of universal references.  But the OP has a "not expanded" error, not a "no overload found" error.

Comment: @Yakk, yeah, as I said my first comment was erroneous since forwarding makes no sense there. And yeah, I actually can't reproduce the issue, an example without the boost stuff would be nice.

Comment: @yakk I posted a new example

Comment: @rudolf I did so, but I get kind of same error generic_callback.cc: In lambda function:
generic_callback.cc:11:15: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
          call(args...);
               ^
generic_callback.cc:11:15: note:         ‘args’
generic_callback.cc:11:19: error: expansion pattern ‘args’ contains no argument packs
          call(args...);

Comment: @rudolf So, I did what you said and It did not work with my g++ but it worked with my clang 3.9

Comment: @SamDaniel well I assume Yakk would be the one to explain everything in detail but after a bit of reading I understand what I said was wrong. What I proposed would just eliminate the perfect forwarding, but you can actually still have it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831382/capturing-perfectly-forwarded-variable-in-lambda

Comment: `auto invoke_me = [=](){ call(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };` should be `auto invoke_me = [=]()mutable{ call(std::move(args)...); };` *assuming* you intend to call the `invoke_me` closure exactly once, but that once may be outside of the current scope and lifetime of the passed in arguments.

Comment: [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4804ec54428285fc) of it working in gcc 6.3 and clang 3.8.

Comment: @yakk auto invoke_me = [=]()mutable{
            call(std::move(args)...);
  }; This works in clang but not with my g++

Comment: btw, Why was it negative voted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test
{
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  void callback_dispatcher(F call, Args&& ...args )
  {   
    std::cout << "callback_dispatcher>" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "enter <<< " << std::endl;                                                 
    auto invoke_me = [=]()mutable{
      call(std::move(args)...);
    };  
    invoke_me();
  }   
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Main entered..." << std::endl;


  test::callback_dispatcher(
    [](int a)
    {
      std::cout << "void(int) lambda dispatched with a = " << a << std::endl;
    },
    5
  );

  std::cout << "Main exited..." << std::endl;
}
```

The above slight change compiles in gcc 4.9 and up, but not in gcc 4.8.5.

It also compiles in modern versions of clang.

Update your compiler, or don't use c++11 features that your compiler doesn't support.

You may be able to pack your args into a tuple, then unpack them in the body of the function.

```
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  void callback_dispatcher(F call, Args&& ...args )
  {   
    std::cout << "callback_dispatcher>" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "enter <<< " << std::endl;                                                 
    auto invoke_me = [tup = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...), call=std::move(call)]()mutable{
      std::apply( call, std::move(tup) );
    };  
    invoke_me();
  }
```

where you now have to implement `std::apply`, which is a C++17 feature, in the limited subset of C++11 you have.  (Don't call it `std::apply`).  This approach will probably work in g++ 4.8.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<std::size_t...Is> struct index_sequence {using type=index_sequence;};
  template<std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is> struct make_index_sequence:make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};
  template<std::size_t...Is> struct make_index_sequence<0,Is...>:index_sequence<Is...>{};
  namespace details {
    template<class F, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    auto apply( ::notstd::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&& tuple )
    -> decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::get<Is>(std::declval<Tuple>())... ) )
    {
      return std::forward<F>(f)( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))... );
    }
  }
  template<class F, class Tuple>
  auto apply( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple )
  -> decltype(::notstd::details::apply( make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) ))
  {
    return ::notstd::details::apply( make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) );
  }
}
```

[live example of C++11 compliant notstd::apply](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f395d1a17f461f31).

Answer (score 2):

If expansion does not work in lambda it is possible to expand the pack outside during creation of functional object and pass it to that lambda.

So instead of:

```cpp
m_timer->async_wait([=](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
    call(std::forward<Args>(args)...); //Error here
});
```

It could be:

```cpp
auto functor = std::bind(std::forward<F>(call), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
m_timer->async_wait([=](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
    functor();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same error with c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) with c++11

```
template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_front(Args&&... args)
    {
        target( [&] {
                     _collection.emplace_front(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                     } );
    }
```

following worked for me!

```
template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_front(Args&&... args)
    {
        target( [&] (Args ...ar) -> void {
                           _collection.emplace_front(ar...);
                           } );
    }
```

i get warning for Args&&... args as unused but easy to fix that.