# How to be explicit about the type of a captured variable in a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, capture

How can I explicitly specify the type of a captured variable for a lambda in C++?

For example, assume I have a function that takes a universal reference and I want to perfect-forward it into a lambda.

I found out, that I can use a `std::tuple` for this as shown below, but I wonder if there is a more succinct way.

```
template<typename T>
auto returns_functor (T&& value)
{
  return [value = std::tuple<T> (std::forward<T> (value))] ()
  {
    /* use std::get<0> (value) */
  };
}
```

Related: [Capturing perfectly-forwarded variable in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831382/capturing-perfectly-forwarded-variable-in-lambda) (the accepted answer there suggests this is a different question, but further answers give essentially the above solution).

Comment: What about calling the lambda with the value instead of capturing it?

Comment: If you keep it a `T` what virtue is there to specify it?

Comment: What's wrong with `value = std::forward<T>(value)`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wouldn't that always capture by copy?

Comment: That doesn't look safe because the rvalue reference will probably be invalid when your function returns, yet you are capturing it into a lambda and returning the lambda. Invoking the lambda will try to use an invalid reference. e.g. `lambda = returns_functor(std::string());` When `returns_functor` returns, the string is destructed, and calling the lambda will use a destroyed object.

Comment: @RaymondChen In that example you pass in an rvalue reference, so it will be moved into a `tuple<string>` and there are no lifetime issues. The possible issue is if you pass in an lvalue reference and then let the lambda outlive it.

Comment: @interjay Duh. Thanks for fixing. The issue still stands with the lvalue reference, thought that's a bit more manageable because the caller has a name for the thing that must remain alive.

Comment: @interjay Why would it? It should copy or move depending on the value category of the argument I think?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It would copy or move, but it would never hold a reference. So it can't be considered perfect forwarding. Besides, if all you needed was to copy or move, then all you'd need to specify was `[value]`.

Comment: By default, they're equivalent to using `auto` type deduction. You can add `&` (and maybe `&&` - not certain) in front of the capture variable name to make it capture by reference instead of by value. I believe you can add `const` as well (but I'm not certain).

Comment: @CruzJean: You cannot use `&&` or `const` there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of capturing rvalue ( universal reference) is as follows,

```
template< typename T>
T getRvalue( T&& temp)
{
  auto lambda = [ rTemp = std::move( temp)]() mutable
  {
     return T( std::forward< T>( rTemp));
  };

  return lambda();
}
```

`std::move()` allows to capture objects of movable type those can't be captured by copy.
`mutable` is very important here in lambda, until `mutable` is not used, objects captured by lambda can't be modified and compile will generate following error,

```
cannot conver 'rTemp (type 'const T') to type 'std::remove_reference<T>::type&' {aka 'T&'}
return T( std::forward< T>( rTemp));
```

Now about first question,
***"How can I explicitly specify the type of a captured variable for a lambda in C++?"***
 So It is not required to specify the type, compile will do it, see following link,
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

It states *`A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable declared with type auto, whose declarative region is the body of the lambda expression.`* In simple words, it means auto variable get deduced according to initializer and doesn't requires to specify it's type explicitly, for example

```
int x = 1;
auto lambda = [ y = x + 2](){ std::cout<< "y = "<< y<< std::endl;};
```

Here `y` would be deduced as `int` by initializer `x + 2`.