# c++ - capturing perfectly forwarded vars in a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm pretty new with c++ and am currently writing an inversion of control container for my first project, expanding on [this blog post](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/567981/anplusiocpluscontainerplususingplusvariadicplustem) by adding registering on base classes and forwarding additional arguments to the constructor.

It works pretty good for now but when I instantiate a lambda multiple times the captured values seem to get overridden.

Example:

```
struct A{
    short a;
    explicit A(short a_) : a(a_) {}
};
struct IC{
    virtual unsigned C() = 0;
};
struct CImpl : public IC{
    explicit CImpl(unsigned c_) : IC(), c(c_) {}
    unsigned C() override{return c;}
private:
    unsigned c;
};
template<class T, typename...TArgs> 
std::function<T*()> AsMinimalAsItGets(TArgs&&...args)
{ 
    return [&args...]() mutable -> T* 
    { 
        return new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...); 
    }; 
} 
auto aFactory = AsMinimalAsItGets<A>(3);
auto cFactory = AsMinimalAsItGets<CImpl>(5);
auto aInst = aFactory();//aInst->a should be 3 but is 5
auto cInst = cFactory();//cInst->C() is 5
```

A gets instantiated with 5 instead of 3.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58400029/10552999) as solution, but it didn't fix the problem.

So how do I correctly capture the variables when instantiating the lambda?
I need to capture in a way that enables me to use perfect forwarding in the lambda

Comment: `&args` becomes a refeence to a temporal../ which coincentrntally changed to the new value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to avoid a copy when you actually need one. In your case, you try to preserve the value categories of the arguments by `std::forward` them. But when you return a factory function `std::function<T*()>`, this closure must own the data it uses to perform the delayed construction. Otherwise, you end up with dangling references, as the arguments passed to `AsMinimalAsItGets` only outlive the scope of the function call.

The fix is easy:

```
template<class T, typename...TArgs> 
std::function<T*()> AsMinimalAsItGets(TArgs&&...args)
{ 
    return [args...]() mutable -> T* 
    //      ^^^^^^^ (1) Copy the arguments into the closure
    { 
        return new T(args...); 
        //           ^^^^^^^ (2) Pass them as is to the ctor
    }; 
}
```

Note that as @HolyBlackCat pointed out, this does not perfectly forward the arguments *into* the lambda capture. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49902823/9593596), in C++20, you can

```
return [...args = std::forward<TArgs>(args)]() mutable -> T* 
{ 
    return new T(args...); 
};
```

while in C++17, you need this workaround:

```
return [args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)]() mutable -> T* 
{ 
    return std::apply([](auto&&... args){ return new T(args...); },
        std::move(args));
};
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail to perfect-forward `args`? The capture has to be `...args = std::forward<TArgs>(args)`, and using `args` inside of the lambda also requires `forward`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for your help, should be fixed now.

Comment: I want to note that std::make_tuple doesn't work for lvalue references, they would be captured by value.
I used std::tuple<TArgs...>(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...) instead and now it works for all values