# Do C++ ranges support projections in views?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I know algorithms (e.g. `sort`) in ranges support projection, but it seems to me that there is no way to get that functionality for views...
Am I right?

As an example consider [following working code](https://godbolt.org/z/j4Psb14sE):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

enum Color {
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
}; 
struct Cat {
   int age;
   Color color;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Cat> cats{{.age = 10,.color=Color::Red}, {.age = 20,.color=Color::Blue}, {.age = 30,.color=Color::Green}};
    auto is_red = [](const auto& cat) {return cat.color == Color::Red;};
    for (const auto& cat: cats | std::views::filter(is_red)) {
        std::cout << cat.age << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the lambda and do something like:

```
for (const auto& cat: cats | std::views::filter(&Cat::color, Color::Red) {
```

note: my question is for member variable projection, but obviously in real code member function calls would be also needed.

Comment: If allowed, syntax would be (to match algorithm) `std::views::filter([](Color color){ return color == Color::Red; }, &Cat::color);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 IDK, I see your point, but it ruins the left to right flow... :)

Comment: `views::transform` + `views::filter` + `.base()` may help.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't see how I can go from the transformed filtered range back to the untransformed elements that where filtered in using `.base()`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont. https://godbolt.org/z/6jvaK6PY1

Comment: @康桓瑋 So we need an iterator remapping view maybe.  Like, `std::views::transform(&Cat::color) | filter_equal(Color::Red) | base_elements | base_elements`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do C++ ranges support projections in views?

No (although range-v3 did<sup>†</sup>).

> Is there a way to remove the lambda and do something like:
>
> ```
> std::views::filter(&Cat::color, Color::Red)
> ```

That wouldn't really be how this would work with projections anyway. It would have been:

```cpp
filter([](Color c){ return c == Color::Red; }, &Cat::color)
```

Which you can reduce this if you have an `equals` that returns a predicate:

```cpp
filter(equals(Color::Red), &Cat::color)
```

---

But adding projections to algorithms is kind of unnecessary. You can always provide a projection manually. Using [Boost.Hof](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/proj.html)'s appropriately-named `proj` function adapter, which satisfies `proj(p, f)(xs...) == f(p(xs)...)` (i.e. we're applying `p` on each argument before passing them into `f`):

```cpp
filter(proj(&Cat::color, [](Color c){ return c == Color::Red; }))
```

or, shorter:

```cpp
filter(proj(&Cat::color, _ == Color::Red))
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EfqGz7YeM).

---

<sup>†</sup>Even in the [range-v3 implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/e7746b214f3cfca341a8aa55fbce95b6b8a1c9d1/include/range/v3/view/remove_if.hpp#L167-L177), it's not that `remove_if_view` had explicit support for projections. It's that the overload that took a projection manually composed the predicate for you as `compose(pred, proj)`. In range-v3, `compose(f, g)(xs...)` can mean either `f(g(xs...))` or `f(g(xs)...)` depending on how `g` is invocable. So in this case, it's a projection rather than function composition. In Boost.Hof, there is are distinct `compose` and `proj` adaptors for the two cases.

Comment: Yes, my use of projection was wrong, I was looking for something like projection + nonexisting filter (in another universe where current filter is named filter_if and filter is checking values, not predicates).

Comment: BTW just noticed the _ in answer, it is nice, but I am a bit concerned that so many libs(e.g. gmock) use it...  But actually that or lambda2 are great for simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer is correct since my use of projection was wrong, I wanted a projection and also equivalent of (assuming `std::filter` in C++ is named `std::filter_if`) imaginary `std::filter` that uses `==` for comparison, like we have `std::count`/`std::count_if` `std::find`/`std::find_if` pairs in STL.

If somebody needs something like this this seems to work, but it has a potential to be slow since perfect forwarding in lambdas is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831382/capturing-perfectly-forwarded-variable-in-lambda) to do, so I did not bother.

( I use keep since it is nicer name for me, but it can also be named `filter_memb`).

```
template<typename Member, typename Val>
auto keep_memb(const Member& memb, const Val& val){
    return std::views::filter([=](auto& object){return std::invoke(memb, object) == val; } );
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j7f91zWjM)