# Why std::erase and std::erase_if don't support projection?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, erase-remove-idiom

C++ ranges are nice, but AFAIK they still "suffer" from the fact that they do not know to modify containers, e.g. if you use `ranges::remove` you still need to do `container.erase(...`

Now there are algorithms that do know how to erase from containers (`std::erase`, `std::erase_if`) but unlike ranges they do not support projection.

My question if this is just because (AFAIK) that functionality was proposed separately from ranges(+ lack of time/lack of proposals), or is there fundamental reason why this functionality is not available.

Comment: Is there a "fundamental" reason why it's remotely necessary? Use a [function adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622901/2069064).

Comment: A range doesn't necessarily have a container behind it.

Comment: @Barry just syntax suggar, for me it is much nicer to write &MyStruct::member_ , but that is a personal style thing...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `erase_if(v, proj(&MyStruct::member_, pred))`?

Comment: @Barry yes, but that is not std:: I know this is a stupid reason, but often it is much easier to sell things to other people when something is in std... but you are right, if one can use Boost then HOF is nice option.

Comment: `std::erase_if( vec, pred )` -- isn't `pred` a projection?  Or is it that you want `std::erase_if(vec, pred(proj) )`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I meant something like: erase(container, 47, &Person::age) -> deletes all persons from container if their age is 47

Answer (score 3):

`std::erase` and `std::erase_if` are not algorithms applicable to any container. They are an overload set of functions that do "the same thing" to many containers.

The associative containers *don't have* `std::erase`, because it would either be inconsistent with their member `erase`, or it would be inconsistent with the sequence container `erase`.

I don't think there is a fundamental incompatibility with having a projection argument in `erase_if`, nor in `erase` where it is present, but they were defined in terms of the existing `std::remove`, `std::remove_if` and member `erase`s and `remove`s, which lack projections.